# Cannot link custom IBDesignable class to UIButton on storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

How do I connect IBDesignable custom class to UIButton?

Code

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class MyButton: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }
}
```

The name of the file is `MyButton.swift`

[image]

It doesn't show MyButton as the class? How would I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only link custom classes to objects of the same type, or a type it inherits from. Instead of

```
@IBDesignable class MyButton: UIView {
```

you probably want

```
@IBDesignable class MyButton: UIButton {
```

or link it to a `UIView` object instead

Comment: I changed to UIButton already but the border of the color doesn't change? is my class correct?

Comment: Its okay I just change the width instead.

Comment: @sinusGob Layer properties do not work directly on UIButton, usually I set a UIView behind it and change that if I need shadow or button borders or something similar

Answer (score 5):

You probably need MyButton to inherit from UIButton, rather than UIView.